# Rearrange a 5D tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 5D tensor in the shape of `(N,C,T,H,W)`. I want to rearrange it using PyTorch to the form of `(N,T,HW,C)`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naturally you can reshape the last two dimensions of your tensor by flattening your tensor from `dim=-2`, this will produce a shape of `(N,C,T,HW)`:

```
>>> x.flatten(-2)
```

Then you can permute the dimensions around:

```
>>> x.flatten(-2).permute(0,2,3,1)
```